# Bubbling events not stopping from propagation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an anchor as follows:

```
<table id="datatable_users">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="#/id=1" class="ClassUpdateConfig btn btn-info btn-right-margin" data-id="1"> 
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>&nbsp;Manage
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have the following event attached:

```
$(document).on('click','.ClassUpdateConfig', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    redirectTo(localeURI+'admin/system/users/edit/'+$(this).attr('data-id'));
});
```

There is already an event attached to the `tr` of the `table` as follows:

```
$("#datatable_users tbody").on("click","tr", function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
});
```

The issue is when I click on the manage button inside the anchor (within the table row `tr`) it selects and highlights the role as well because of the `tr event associated`. How do I stop this from occurring? If they click on the button I do not want the `tr` to be selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest to make sure the handler doesn't trigger when clicking the anchor, would be to just add a condition

```
$("#datatable_users tbody").on("click", "tr", function(e){
    if ( $(e.target).closest('a').length === 0 ) {
        $(this).toggleClass("selected");
    }   
});
```

The reason stopping the propagation doesn't work, is because the handler is attached to the `document`, not the element.

If these elements aren't inserted dynamically, you could solve the issue by not delegating the event to the `document` level at all.

Comment: i cannot change the document  call but what does closest do?

Comment: It checks if the clicked element *(target)* has a parent element somewhere up the chain that has the matching class, or if the element itself has that class, thus ensuring that the `toggleClass` only fires when `.ClassUpdateConfig` or any of it's descendants isn't clicked.

Comment: As an FYI, you shouldn't generally delegate to the document, and certainly not if the elements aren't inserted dynamically.

Comment: I've edited to include just anchors, as you seem to not want to use classnames

Comment: just out of curiosity what would be the closest element to my manage button?

Comment: The closest anchor would be ... the anchor, the one with the class `ClassUpdateConfig`?

Comment: Sorry im just not understanding how this works. Can you explain the conditions for closest for both the tr and the manage button

Comment: I see. so there is no anchor up the DOM for a tr element.

Comment: When someone clicks the anchor, they can click an element inside the anchor as well. In this case, someone could click the icon, and if so, the `span` would be the `event.target` element, not the anchor. `closest()` takes the span, and checks if it has an anchor as a parent. If the anchor itself was used with `closest()`, then it would stop right away, as that element matches etc. It's just a way to make sure that `event.target` catches everything inside the anchor, even if the anchor wasn't the element clicked, but the span inside it etc.

Comment: Right so here we are executing on the table row and that has no anchor up the tree 1 level which gives a length of 0

Comment: What would happen if there was an anchor above the table? wouldnt it not select since the closest would not be 0?

Comment: Yes, if the entire table for some reason was inside an anchor, it wouldn't work, which is why one generally uses more specific selectors, like ID's and classes.

Comment: You can pass an element as the second parameter to closest to negate going up the entire tree but only as far as the passed parameter eleemnt

Comment: @jkushner - yes you can, and it's a good idea. If the OP *did* have the table inside an anchor, he could limit the search with `$(e.target).closest('a', '#datatable_users')` to avoid issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Event.stopImmediatePropagation()`, as noted by MDN:

> If several listeners are attached to the same element for the same
>   event type, they are called in order in which they have been added. If
>   during one such call, event.stopImmediatePropagation() is called, no
>   remaining listeners will be called.

Comment: nope does not work it still highlights the table row when i click on manage

Answer (score 0):

You can test if the element is the parent container

```
   $("#datatable_users tbody").on("click", "tr", function(e){
      if(e.target === this){
        $(this).toggleClass("selected");
      }
    });
```

Edit:
The approach above might not work well as `e.target` gets the inner most element, which is usually `td` rather than `tr`. The following approach works better by checking explicitly the target element type:

```
   $("#datatable_users tbody").on("click", "tr", function(e){
      if(!$(e.target).is('a')){
        $(this).toggleClass("selected");
      }
    });
```

Comment: this doesnt work but its what im looking for so i dont have to manually hard code the class names

Comment: This should work, except that `e.target` might tend to return `td` instead of `tr`. In that case you might want to bind it to `td`instead.